# Download file from database asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am reading PDF data from a database field (database field format is 'Data') and I have converted it into bytes using data reader GetBytes and I have it right because it's working fine in other operation.

I added a button on aspx page, and, on button click, I have the below code to download it:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename="test.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
Response.End();
```

But it's not doing any thing. I mean when I click the button I can step through it but after `response.end()` nothing happens.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the type of "data" variable? What is your database, and what is the length of the data.Data ?

Comment: Also, try adding .pdf extension to the end of your file name.

Comment: what happens if you add this `Response.Flush();` before the `Response.End();` if that doesn't work try writing the following in place of your `BinaryWrite(data.Data)`
`Response.BinaryWrite(data.ToArray());` or what ever data.Data is do 
`Response.BinaryWrite(data.Data.ToArray());` also be sure to clear the following before calling the .AddHeader `Response.ClearHeaders();`

Comment: which browser you are using?

Comment: @OguzOzgul 'data' type is my own class that gives me 'Data' which is byte[] type.  I am using Sql Server 2008R2 and data.Data length is 356863

Comment: @MethodMan i tried adding Response.Flush() before .End() and added .ClearHeaders() and also tried .ToArray() .. nothing seems to work ...

Comment: can you show all related code that pertains to your question.. it think that it would make it much easier for others as well as myself to see what it is you're doing or not doing..

Comment: Can you see with a network analyzer whether the client receives the response or not?

Comment: What else you have on your aspx page, including backend also? Can you show/describe what you have on your page?

Comment: @OguzOzgul i don't think i quite understand what you want me to look

Comment: @Angloos i have a simple aspx button, a file upload panel and an unpdate panel

Comment: hmm if you are using Chrome can you click F12 when you running your app and see if you are getting any error? if your button is inside your update panel that might be the issue

Comment: If you post the file in an update panel, I don't think it will be downloaded to the client. You need to add a postback trigger to your update panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your button outside of update panel. You also need to add postback trigger as Oguz Ozgul mentioned it. Additionally you should add ThreadAbortException catch also just to stay safe...